# Go equivalent of a void pointer in C

Tags: pointers, go

I've been playing around with Go a little bit making some data structure libraries and I have one big problem. I want the data structure to be able to contain any type, but I don't see any way to do this in Go because you can't declare void pointers and they don't have a class like NSObject that everything inherits from. How would I achieve this same functionality in Go?

Comment: The other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166558/generic-structs-with-go

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [the Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec):

> A type implements any interface comprising any subset of its methods and may therefore implement several distinct interfaces. For instance, all types implement the *empty interface*:
>
> ```
> interface{}
> ```

If you search within that document for `interface{}`, you'll see quite a few examples of how you can use it to do what you want.

---

**Update** (2023-09-27): Starting in Go 1.18 (March 2022), Go provides the builtin alias `any`. Per [its documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#any):

> ```
> type any = interface{}
> ```
>
> any is an alias for interface{} and is equivalent to interface{} in all ways.

This addition was related to the addition of support for generics, also in Go 1.18, which slightly reconceptualized how interfaces work (though in a completely compatible way). Here's the current spec language:

> Every type that is a member of the type set of an interface implements that interface. Any given type may implement several distinct interfaces. For instance, all types implement the *empty interface* which stands for the set of all (non-interface) types:
>
> ```
> interface{}
> ```
>
> For convenience, the predeclared type `any` is an alias for the empty interface.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for your answer. I just modified my LinkedList to use a type which implements the blank interface. Pretty awesome how simple it is to achieve something like that with the interface and loose typing.