# What is the Golang equivalent of a void pointer

Tags: c, go

I am already familiar with C and I've been working on improving my Golang skills. Anyone know how to create something reminiscent of a void * in Golang?

For example:

```
struct Node {
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
}
```

Comment: I thought it was `interface{}`, but I don't even know Go.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an empty interface, (`interface {}`), and modify it to what you want. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8996797/6525260)). This is known as an empty interface, and it can embody *any* type.