# Generic Structs with Go

Tags: go, generics, struct

What is the equivalent of this C# code in Go, how can I build it

```cs
    class ModelX<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }

    ModelX<int>
```

I have tried something like:

```
    type ModelX<T> struct {
        ModelY
        Data []T
    }

    m := ModelX<T>
```

How to do this? Is that possible?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Starting with Go 1.18, you can define [generic types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations):

```
type Model[T any] struct {
    Data []T
}
```

A generic type must be instantiated<sup>1</sup> when used, and instantiation requires a type parameter list:

```
func main() {
    // passing int as type parameter
    modelInt := Model[int]{Data: []int{1, 2, 3}}
    fmt.Println(modelInt.Data) // [1 2 3]

    // passing string as type parameter
    modelStr := Model[string]{Data: []string{"a", "b", "c"}}
    fmt.Println(modelStr.Data) // [a b c]
}
```

More info and common gotchas about instantiations: [Go error: cannot use generic type without instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274361)

If you declare methods on a generic type, you must repeat the type parameter declaration on the receiver, even if the type parameters are not used in the method scope — in which case you may use the blank identifier `_` to make it obvious:

```
func (m *Model[T]) Push(item T) {
    m.Data = append(m.Data, item)
}

// not using the type param in this method
func (m *Model[_]) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(m.Data)
}
```

An important detail is that — unlike functions<sup>2</sup> —, generic types must always supply all<sup>3</sup> type parameters upon instantiation. For example, this type:

```
type Foo[T any, P *T] struct {
    val T
    ptr P
}
```

must be instantiated with both types, even if some of them could be inferred:

```
func main() {
    v := int64(20)
    foo := Foo[int64, *int64]{val:v, ptr: &v}

    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/n2G6l6ozacj

---

Footnotes:

1: Language specs about instantiations: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Instantiations

2: The quote from the specs is *"Calls to parameterized functions may provide a (possibly partial) type argument list, or may omit it entirely if the omitted type arguments are inferrable from the ordinary (non-type) function arguments."*. This quote excludes parametrized types

3: in early beta releases, the type param list in generic types could be partial; this feature has been [disabled](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51527).

Comment: Adding a `func NewModel[T any](data []T) Model[T] { return Model[T]{data} }` can DRY some use cases a bit by leveraging type inference; you then can do, e.g., `modelInt := NewModel([]int{1, 2, 3})` without repeating the `int`.
See https://go.dev/play/p/t-brVDwpQ-V