# Go error: cannot use generic type without instantiation

Tags: go, generics

Studying Go generics, I'm running into an error I can't seem to untangle. I've boiled it down to the simplest code:

```
type opStack[T any] []T

func main() {

    t := make(opStack)
    //  t := new(opStack)
    t = append(t, 0)
    fmt.Println(t[0])
}
```

In playground, this bonks at the `make()` call (and similarly on the `new` call that's commented out) with the following error message:

> cannot use generic type opStack[T any] without instantiation

But `make()` is an instantiating function. So, I expect I'm missing some syntactical subtlety. What is Go complaining about and what's the needed correction?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Whenever you use a parametrized type, **including anywhere a type argument is required, like in the built-in `make`**, you must replace the type parameters in its definition with actual types. This is called instantiation.

```
t := make(opStack[int], 0)
t = append(t, 0)
```

A generic type must be instantiated also if you use it as a type argument to *another* generic type:

```
type Data[T any] struct {
    data T
}

d := Data[opStack[int]]{ data: []int{0, 1, 2} }
```

You can instantiate with a type parameter, for example in function signatures, fields and type definitions:

```
type FooBar[T any] struct {
    ops opStack[T]
}

type OpsMap[T any] map[string]opStack[T]

func echo[T any](ops opStack[T]) opStack[T] { return ops }
```

The relevant quotes from the language specs are (currently) in two different places, [Type definitions](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions):

> If the type definition specifies type parameters, the type name denotes a generic type. Generic types **must be instantiated when they are used**.

and [Instantiations](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Instantiations)

> A generic function or type is **instantiated** by substituting type arguments for the type parameters. [...]

In other programming languages, "instantiation" may refer to creating an instance of an object — in Go the term specifically refers to replacing type params with concrete types. In my view, the usage of the term is still consistent, although in Go it doesn't necessarily imply allocation.

---

Note that you may call generic functions without explicit type arguments. Instantiation happens there too, simply the type arguments might all be inferred from the function arguments:

```
func Print[T, U any](v T, w U) { /* ... */ }

Print("foo", 4.5) // T is inferred from "foo", U from 4.5
```

Inference used to work also in generic *types*, with the restriction that the type parameter list had to be non-empty. However this feature has been disabled, so you must supply all type params explicitly.

```
type Vector[T any] []T 
// v := Vector[int]{} -> must supply T

type Matrix[T any, U ~[]T] []U 
// m := Matrix[int, []int]{} -> must supply T and U
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful reply. I'm not sure about your first code snippet: make() accepts `any` without requiring the type to be defined: `t := make(opStack[any], 0)` See it at line 10 in the [playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/px5guWqmVL5?v=gotip) I set up.

Comment: @platypusguy The first code snippet is just meant to illustrate that you have to supply a type param to instantiate `opStack` and use it in `make`. `opStack[any]` is also an instantiation with `any`, which is alias of `interface{}`, which is a type.

Answer (score 3):

because you want

> t = append(t, 0)

the data type can be int or float group.

this code should work

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type opStack[T any] []T

    t := make(opStack[int], 0) // You must initialize data type here
    t = append(t, 0)
    fmt.Println(t[0])
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I slightly changed your correction to reflect the `any` aspect, which also works:

`t := make(opStack[any], 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for detailed explanation on it. I was trying to find the answer for a related question on how to do `struct typing` with generics [Go Structural typing with Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76386802/go-structural-typing-with-generics). I found the way to do it thought it might be helpful in similar cases.

```golang
package main

type Queue[T any] struct {
}

// Get implements Ops.
func (*Queue[T]) Get() T {
    panic("unimplemented")
}

type Ops[T any] interface {
    Get() T
}

var _ Ops[any] = new(Queue[any])
```