# Go generics: syntax of generic type constraints

Tags: go, generics, syntax, type-constraints

In the Go Language reference, on the section regarding [Type parameter declarations](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations), I see `[P Constraint[int]]` as a type parameter example.

What does it mean?
How to use this structure in a generic function definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a type parameter list, as defined in the paragraph you linked, that has one type parameter declaration that has:

- `P` as the type parameter name
- `Constraint[int]` as the constraint

whereas `Constraint[int]` is an [instantiation](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Instantiations) of a generic type (you *must* always instantiate generic types upon usage).

In that paragraph of the language spec, `Constraint` isn't defined, but it could reasonably be a generic interface:

```
type Constraint[T any] interface {
    DoFoo(T)
}

type MyStruct struct {}

// implements Constraint instantiated with int
func (m MyStruct) DoFoo(v int) { 
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

And you can use it as you would use any type parameter constraint:

```
func Foo[P Constraint[int]](p P) {
    p.DoFoo(200)
}

func main() {
    m := MyStruct{} // satisfies Constraint[int]
    Foo(m)
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/aBgva62Vyk1

<sup>The usage of this constraint is obviously contrived: you could simply use that instantiated interface as type of the argument.</sup>

For more details about implementation of generic interfaces, you can see: [How to implement generic interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72034479/how-to-implement-generic-interfaces/72050933#72050933)