# How to satisfy a constraint implemented through embedding in generics?

Tags: go, generics, constraints, embedding

I have an interface

```
type FooInterface interface {
    HasName() bool
}
```

It has a base implementation that I intend to use in other implementation of FooInterface

```
type FooBoilerplate struct {
    hasName bool
}

func (f *FooBoilerplate) HasName() bool {
    return f.hasName
}
```

Like so

```
type Foo1 struct {
    fooId int
    FooBoilerplate
}

func (f *Foo1) GetId() int {
    return f.fooId
}
```

I want to create a container class for FooInterface using generics

```
type FooContainer[T FooInterface] struct {
    list []T
}

func (fc *FooContainer[T]) AddItem() {
    var t T

    fc.list = append(fc.list, t)

}
```

However I get compilation errors when I try to instantiate the container

```
func RunThis() {
    foo1 := Foo1{FooBoilerplate: FooBoilerplate{hasName: false}}

    // works fine
    TakesFooInterface(&foo1)

    // doesnt compile
    fc := FooContainer[Foo1]{}
    fc.AddItem()
}
```

Not sure why Foo1 is seen to implement FooInterface when passed to a function, but isnt when passed tot he container struct. I cant pass an object to the container instantiation either.

Comment: marginally related: [How to implement generic interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72034479/how-to-implement-generic-interfaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo1` doesn't implement `FooInterface`. `*Foo1` does. This is true irrespective of whether the interface is used as the type of a function argument or as a constraint.

That is why you pass `&foo1` (type `*Foo1`) to `TakesFooInterface` and not `foo1` (type `Foo1`).

Likewise for the type parameter, you should instantiate the generic type with `*Foo1`:

```
fc := FooContainer[*Foo1]{}
```

Comment: Pointer to a class and not an object?

Comment: @ShreyGhildiyal I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Pointers usually are memory addresses right? That means some object needs to be present, unless we are pointing to  nil address. A class is not an object right?

Comment: @ShreyGhildiyal "class" and "object" are both incorrect terminology in Go. `*Foo1` is a type just as `Foo1` is a type. If `var foo1 Foo1` then `foo1` is of type `Foo1` and `&foo1` is of type `*Foo1`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your TakesFooInterface is like this:

```
func TakesFooInterface(foo1 FooInterface) {
   ...
}
```

Then the call TakesFooInterface(foo1) failed to compile, as foo1 does not implement FooInterface but &foo1.

The same with your generic case, the `Foo1` type does not implement FooInterface which requires the pointer access in the method `HasName` but `*Foo1` type does.

I have copied your code with some of my tryings on Go.Dev: https://go.dev/play/p/3I2mtabi-ub