# Dynamic conversion between generic interfaces of different types

Tags: go, generics, adapter

Suppose I have following generic interface:

```golang
type Iface[T any] interface {
    MyFunc(T)
}
```

I would like to implement "adapter" or "converter" class, which helps to convert between interfaces of different types. Essentially, it wraps `Iface[A]` to behave like an `Iface[B]`:

```golang
type Adapter[A any, B any] interface {
    Adapt(Iface[A]) Iface[B]
}
```

So, I can't figure out how to write `Adapt` function:

```golang
type Iface[T any] interface {
    MyFunc(T)
}

type Adapter[A any, B any] interface {
    Adapt(Iface[A]) Iface[B]
}

type StringToIntAdapter struct {
}

func (StringToIntAdapter) Adapt(Iface[string]) Iface[Int] {
    // ???
}
```

I think I would need to somehow dynamically create a new instance of an interface inside of an adapter. But I can't find any tips out how to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically create a new instance of an interface"? Types don't actually implement generic interfaces, they implement instantiations of generic interfaces. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72050933/11381693

Comment: What's the _actual_ purpose of the "generic interface" Iface? Maybe your use of "generics" is warranted.

Comment: To put it another way; you can't dynamically convert to a generic interface type at runtime, because generics don't exist at runtime -- they are a compile-time type specialization which is why you need an instantiation.