# Is there anyway to combine two generic model into one

Tags: go, generics

```golang
type TodoUpdateLog struct {
    ID               uint                   `json:"id"`
    Name             Range[string]          `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Status           Range[string]          `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Desc             Range[json.RawMessage] `json:"desc,omitempty"`              
    Priority         Range[string]          `json:"priority,omitempty"`          
    EstimatedStartDT Range[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_start_dt,omitempty"` 
    EstimatedEndDT   Range[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_end_dt,omitempty"`   
    Owners           Range[[]string]        `json:"owners,omitempty"`            
    Followers        Range[[]string]        `json:"followers,omitempty"`         
}

type TodoUpdateRequest struct {
    ID               uint                      `json:"id"`
    Name             Optional[string]          `json:"name,omitempty"` 
    Status           Optional[string]          `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Desc             Optional[json.RawMessage] `json:"desc,omitempty"`              
    Priority         Optional[string]          `json:"priority,omitempty"`          
    EstimatedStartDT Optional[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_start_dt,omitempty"` 
    EstimatedEndDT   Optional[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_end_dt,omitempty"`   
    Owners           Optional[[]string]        `json:"owners,omitempty"`            
    Followers        Optional[[]string]        `json:"followers,omitempty"`         
}

type TodoUpdate[T any] struct {
    ID               uint                      `json:"id"`
    Name             T[string]          `json:"name,omitempty"` 
    Status           T[string]          `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Desc             T[json.RawMessage] `json:"desc,omitempty"`              
    Priority         T[string]          `json:"priority,omitempty"`          
    EstimatedStartDT T[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_start_dt,omitempty"` 
    EstimatedEndDT   T[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_end_dt,omitempty"`   
    Owners           T[[]string]        `json:"owners,omitempty"`            
    Followers        T[[]string]        `json:"followers,omitempty"`         
}
```

i have two models "TodoUpdateLog" and "TodoUpdateRequest",  both of two models have same fields and same json tag. The difference between two models is only the type

now i want to combine two models into one,is there anyway to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

What about having a single type and using it in (naming it with the) two different contexts?

```golang
type TodoUpdateLogOrRequest struct {
    ID               uint                   `json:"id"`
    Name             Range[string]          `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Status           Range[string]          `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Desc             Range[json.RawMessage] `json:"desc,omitempty"`              
    Priority         Range[string]          `json:"priority,omitempty"`          
    EstimatedStartDT Range[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_start_dt,omitempty"` 
    EstimatedEndDT   Range[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_end_dt,omitempty"`   
    Owners           Range[[]string]        `json:"owners,omitempty"`            
    Followers        Range[[]string]        `json:"followers,omitempty"`         
}



func main() {
    var updateLog, updateRequest TodoUpdateLogOrRequest
    fmt.Println(updateLog, updateRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You cannot parametrize a parametrized type, because [generic types cannot be used without instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274361/go-error-cannot-use-generic-type-without-instantiation/71282839#71282839).

What you want to do is:

```
t := TodoUpdate[Range]{}
u := TodoUpdate[Optional]{}
```

where `Range` and `Optional` are the type parameters that are replaced in `TodoUpdate`'s type definition and instantiated only then. That looks like a macro instead of parametric polymorphism. The language doesn't support this.

Your alternative is to define an interface, and use that instead of the specific types:

```
type Type[T any] interface {
    // some methods implemented by Range[T] and Optional[T]
    // ...
}

type TodoUpdate struct {
    ID               uint                  `json:"id"`
    Name             Type[string]          `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Status           Type[string]          `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Desc             Type[json.RawMessage] `json:"desc,omitempty"`
    Priority         Type[string]          `json:"priority,omitempty"`
    EstimatedStartDT Type[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_start_dt,omitempty"`
    EstimatedEndDT   Type[time.Time]       `json:"estimate_end_dt,omitempty"`
    Owners           Type[[]string]        `json:"owners,omitempty"`
    Followers        Type[[]string]        `json:"followers,omitempty"`
}
```

And then construct instances of `TodoUpdate` by setting its fields to values of either `Range[T]` or `Optional[T]`:

```
func NewTodoUpdateLog() TodoUpdate {
    return TodoUpdate{
        Name:             Range[string]{},    // implements Type[string]
        EstimatedStartDT: Range[time.Time]{}, // implements Type[time.Time]
        // other fields
    }
}

func NewTodoUpdateRequest() TodoUpdate {
    return TodoUpdate{
        Name:             Optional[string]{},    // implements Type[string]
        EstimatedStartDT: Optional[time.Time]{}, // implements Type[time.Time]
        // other fields
    }
}
```