# How can I use generic method in Go?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I prepared GORM methods in Database.go and I want to keep them generic. The reason I do this is to avoid duplicate codes. I have prepared frequently used operations as below.

```
package database

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go-microservice/internal/constants"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/schema"
    "time"
)

type DbOperations[T any] interface {
    Ready() bool
    GetAll(ctx context.Context) ([]T, error)
    GetByParam(ctx context.Context, param any) (any, error)
    Create(ctx context.Context, data any) error
    Update(ctx context.Context, data any) error
    Delete(ctx context.Context, model any, param any) error
}

type DbConnection[T any] struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}

func NewDatabaseConnection[T any]() DbConnection[T] {
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%d sslmode=%s",
        constants.Host,
        constants.User,
        constants.Password,
        constants.Dbname,
        constants.Port,
        constants.SSLMode)

    db, _ := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            TablePrefix: "wisdom.",
        },
        NowFunc: func() time.Time {
            return time.Now().UTC()
        },
        QueryFields: true})

    return DbConnection[T]{DB: db}
}

func (db *DbConnection[T]) Ready() bool {
    var ready string
    tx := db.DB.Raw("SELECT 1 as ready").Scan(&ready)
    if tx.Error != nil {
        return false
    }
    if ready == "1" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func (db *DbConnection[T]) GetAll(ctx context.Context) ([]T, error) {
    list := make([]T, 0)
    result := db.DB.WithContext(ctx).Find(&list)
    return list, result.Error
}

func (db *DbConnection[T]) GetByParam(ctx context.Context, param any) (any, error) {
    var model any
    result := db.DB.WithContext(ctx).Where(param).Find(&model)
    return model, result.Error
}

func (db *DbConnection[T]) Create(ctx context.Context, data any) error {
    result := db.DB.WithContext(ctx).Create(data)
    return result.Error
}

func (db *DbConnection[T]) Update(ctx context.Context, data any) error {
    result := db.DB.WithContext(ctx).Model(data)
    return result.Error
}

func (db *DbConnection[T]) Delete(ctx context.Context, model any, param any) error {
    result := db.DB.WithContext(ctx).Delete(model, param)
    return result.Error
}
```

When I want to use these methods, for example db_products, I want to pull the method and use it, but when I do this I get an error. db_products.go codes are as follows:

```
package database

import (
    "context"
    "go-microservice/internal/models"
)

type ProductOperations interface {
    GetAllProducts(ctx context.Context) ([]models.Products, error)
}

func (db *DbConnection[T]) GetAllProducts(ctx context.Context) ([]models.Products, error) {
    var re []models.Products
    re, _ = db.GetAll(ctx)
    return re, nil
}
```

But, here I am getting error from IDE. The error is as follows:

```
Cannot assign []T to re (type []models.Products) in multiple assignment
```

How do I solve this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

There is a difference between `any` in type parameter and `any` in regular function parameter. Your case is the former one for generics. So you need to instantiate `T`(decide `T`'s concrete type) first when assigning it to the concrete variables

#### In detail

[Type definition spec](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions)

> If the type definition specifies type parameters, the type name denotes a generic type. Generic types must be instantiated when they are used.

[Instantiations spec](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Instantiations)

> A generic function or type is instantiated by substituting type arguments for the type parameters. [...]

It's because in `GetAllProducts`, type `T` is not decided yet. So it is impossible to assign `[]models.Products` to `T`.

```golang
func (db *DbConnection[T]) GetAllProducts() {
    var re []models.Products
    re, _ = db.GetAll()
}
```

But you can assign `models.Products` to `T` if `T` is decided as `models.Products`, like this.

```golang
db := DbConnection[models.Products]{}
var re []models.Products
re, _ = db.GetAll()
```

I reproduce your problem in the simplified version(https://go.dev/play/p/GHkDThFLOKG). You can find the same error `GetAllProducts()` but in the main code, it works.

#### References

- [Go error: cannot use generic type without instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274361/go-error-cannot-use-generic-type-without-instantiation)
- [Difference between any/interface{} as constraint vs. type of argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71628061/difference-between-any-interface-as-constraint-vs-type-of-argument)

Comment: But this time I cannot access the db via the "(db *DbConnection[T])" instance. If I use "dbs := DbConnection[models.Products]{}", I get an error during runtime. Products is a json, there is also Customers like it. So I need to access *gorm.DB in DbConnection. How can I do it? Thank you for your help, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @ahmtkzk You're welcome. I hope I can help you. But I think it is hard to know what you really want to do in this question. I just answered why your IDE showed Cannot assign `[]T` to `re` (type `[]models.Products`) in multiple assignment. It's because you wanted to assign GetAll output (`[]T`) to your concrete typed variable `re`. It is impossible because `[]T` is a type parameter but `re` is a concrete type `[]models.Products`. Would you supplement your question in detail?

Comment: I think getting an error during runtime when instantiating `T` as `models.Products` in `DbConnection[T]` is a different problem in this question. For debugging it, I think we need more codes such as `go-microservice/internal/models`

Comment: In database.go, I have included basic gorm operations in (db *Db Connection[T]) methods. For example, "func (db *DbConnection[T]) GetAll(ctx context.Context) ([]T, error) {
 list := make([]T, 0)
 result := db.DB.WithContext(ctx).Find(&list)
 return list, result.Error
}" Since I have more than one model, instead of repeating these operations one by one in each of them, I want to use the GetAll method under DbOperations and return it because the return type is generic.

Comment: For example, where I use this generic method is the "GetAllProducts(ctx context.Context) ([]models.Products, error)" method in the ProductOperations interface, which is a special interface in db_products.go. In this method, what I want to do is to use it as db.GetAll(ctx) via (db *DbConnection[T]). I want it to return whatever json struct model I give as the return type because the project will grow and I want it not to be complicated. I got an IDE error while dealing with this. I want to set up this structure in general. If there is a need for detail, I can give details again.

Comment: I understand your intention that you want to remove duplicated logics among models at gorm operations. But in my opinion, it will be helpful to find why it gives an error when when instantiating `T` as models.Products in `DbConnection[T]`. Because even though you use generic, you need to instantiate `T` as a concrete type before using it. I feel like you want to use generic as if it is `interface{}`(`any`)

Comment: Yes, I actually want to use it as interface{}(any). I want it to return whatever model I give it (for example models.Products, models.Customers, models.Vendors). But, I couldn't use the generic operation the way I use it in Java. I will try to get the error as you said.